# How to implement "change your profile picture" feature (server side)

Tags: ruby, iframe, request, server, backend

Im trying to implement a feature on my project, so users can change their profile picture. I'm currently at the point where everything on the front end works (when you hover the mouse over the image it shows camera and when you click it, you can browse through your computer to select an image file) Yet, it doesnt work after that point.
I'm not really sure how to handle server request.

FYI
im using routes.rb and controller .rb files to handle backend.
Also,
should i use iframe, instead of form tag in html?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an iFrame. Simple `form-for` ruby helper will help in this case. I will suggest you to use a file-uploading gem like [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip).

***Create a model for your records:***

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

(*I am supposing the model name to be user*)

***Create a new migration with generator:***

`rails generate paperclip user avatar`

***Update your html form as follow:***

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => users_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do    |form| %>
  <%= form.file_field :avatar %>
<% end %>
```

***Then do following changes in the controller:***

```
def create
  @user = User.create( user_params )
end

private

def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:avatar)
end
```

***To display image anyware on the page use the following helper:***

`<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url %>`

This is the easiest way to handle image uploading at server side in rails. You can read more at the paperclip github page.If you don't want to use a *gem* then then there is a ruby class `FileUtils` which can help you in achieving same goal.